# memory leak when creating local opencv mat object

Tags: c++, opencv, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have a function that I make a mat operation.

```
  void my_func()

   {

     vector<Point> my_vect=another_func();

     Mat my_array((int)my_vect.size(),1,CV_8UC1); //This line is reported as leakage

     for(int i=0;i<my_vect.size();i++)

     my_array.at<uchar>(i,1)=Other_image.at<uchar>(my_vect[i]); 

   }
```

Comment: And another_func() is...?

Comment: @lundin function pushs data on it

Comment: If you have a memory leak, use valgrind to analyze the leak.

Answer (score 1):

no idea about the leak, but there's also at least one buffer overflow.

```
Mat my_array( 17, 1, CV_8UC1 ); // 17 rows, 1 col
for(int i=0; i<17; i++)
     // should be (i,0) below, (i,1) is already out of bounds
     my_array.at<uchar>(i,1) = Other_image.at<uchar>(my_vect[i]); // <-- this looks broken, too
```